# Problems while compiling glib on ubuntu amd64

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, glib

I am trying to build latest gtkmm on ubuntu 11.04 amd64 machine which requires glib as one of its dependency. But there is this error while trying to use make command after ./configure.

The error is :

```
./.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `g_cclosure_marshal_BOOLEAN__BOXED_BOXED'
./.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__PARAM'
./.libs/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `g_cclosure_marshal_BOOLEAN__FLAGS'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[4]: *** [gobject-query] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/test/glib/gobject'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/test/glib/gobject'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
```

The output of `./configure` command is:
http://pastebin.com/DSyQrF1c

The output of `make command` with errors is:
http://pastebin.com/bAgd3UiK

Comment: The glib mentioned in question is fetched from the git repository of gnome-project

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
find .|grep libgobject-2.0.so|xargs ldd
```

and

```
fgrep -r g_cclosure_marshal_ *
```

and try to figure out where the corresponding code is.

Perhaps an additional library -l.. might help
or there is a -D... missing, so that some code isn't included.

I wanted to try it but I don't know if you're talking about repository or release

```
  git clone git://git.gnome.org/glib
```

or

```
wget http://ftp.acc.umu.se/pub/gnome/sources/glib/2.29/glib-2.29.10.tar.bz2
```